# jQuery validation- Input Value combination of number and letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have this function to check whether the input have number and letter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var newtext = $.trim($('#inputtext').val());
        if newtext(condition here){
            alert("Should contain at least one letter and number");
        }
    });
})
```

How can I check if the input value consist of combination of letters and numbers?

**Tried this and works!**

```
if(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test(newtext) == false) {
            alert ("Should contain at least one letter and number.");
}
```

Comment: I have tried the duplicate answer and it works. Thanks for the help. Didn't find that when I try searching. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)